# Expected LBRACE Error; bracket placement it wants doesn't make sense

Tags: css, syntax-error, themes

i've barely coded anything the moment, most of what i know comes from ctrl + shift + i -ing a page i'm on and just kind of making connections based on an already made theme script i have downloaded, so apologies in advance if the solution to this is fairly obvious.

despite not knowing jack about coding, i've been making minor modifications to a youtube theme i downloaded from stylish by copy-pasting bits from inspecting the page, only changing things like the color, and somehow haven't run into any problems... except for this one. i'm getting the "expected LBRACE at line 288 col 49" error and there's a red underline underneath the 'f' in 'focus'.

```
.comment-simplebox-frame:not(yt-uix-form-error)focus, .comment-simplebox-frame {
    border-color: #ff89e5;
}
```

so i'm assuming it's wanting me to put a brace before the 'focus' but i don't really understand why it would want that so i'm guessing that's not what i'm supposed to do. i know there are other posts about beginners asking this same question, but i really can't figure this out. help?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your CSS is incorrect, you shouldn't use the focus selector like this. It's `:focus`, check the [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)
If you don't feel confident with complicated structures, try to achieve the same by using simpler CSS, e.g. instead add a separate class for `yt-uix-form-error`. It's usually easier to trace the error in this case.